# Enable zoom feature in custom template in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, requirejs, requirejs-config.js

I am creating zoom feature on images in my custom template,

**app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
 paths: {
        'custom_zoom': 'Vendor_Module/js/jquery.zoom.js'
 },
shim: {
    'custom_zoom': {
        deps: ['jquery']    
    }
 }
};
```

and in **app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/custom.phtml**

```
 <style>        
  .contain { 
    position: fixed; 
    right: 15%; 
    top: 15%; 
    width: 200px; 
    height: 220px; 
}       
</style>
<div><img class="imgsrc" src="image url here" /></div>

<div class="contain"></div> 

<script type="text/javascript">
require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui','custom_zoom'], function($){ 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.imgsrc') 
        .parent() 
        .zoom({ 
            magnify: 4, 
            target: $('.contain').get(0) 
        }); 
 });
```

Moved jquery.zoom.js into **Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js** directory

But I am getting this error in console in my custom page.

> Script error for: custom_zoom

Can anyone help me on this please.. Thanks

Comment: The error could be anyting. Can you provide more information about the error, or is this everything you get (maybe at least a backtrace or something like this) ?

Comment: @Ekk4rd, pls tell me what more information i have to update here?can you  please use the same code in your test module and check it once

Comment: There might be an issue in the `requirejs-config.js` file. Please check if the `paths` and `shim` configured correctly here: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/requirejs.html#requirejs-config-paths

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think problem in your **requirejs-config.js** file, please update like this

```
var config = {
 paths: {
    custom_zoom: 'Vendor_Module/js/jquery.zoom'
 },
  shim: {
    "custom_zoom": ["jquery"],
 }
};
```

**I hope this may help you!!!**